# pass the read data in server.R into ui.R using shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

In **ui.R**, I read at first a fixed sample data

```
datT2<-fread(paste0('./data/','30062019KRB.csv'),header=TRUE, sep=";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE , encoding="UTF-8")
```

to extract the data structure. 
however there are many data like `30062019KRB.csv` whose structure varies a little bit from each other.

[image]

In the next step in `ui`, I choose one name or one file  and pass it to `server.R`

**ui.R**:

```
 selectInput(inputId = 'date',
          label = 'Stichtag:',
          choices = list.files('./data', full.names = FALSE,
                   recursive = FALSE)),
```

and in **server.R**:

I load the data based on the file name (for instance: 30062018KRB.csv)

```
  data <- reactive({
    infile <- input$date
    if (is.null(infile)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    daS<-fread(paste0('./data/',infile),header=TRUE, sep=";")
    daS[is.na(data)]<- 0
    daS
  })
```

Now my question is: How can I pass the output of `data <- reactive({ ...` to `ui.R` in other words I want to set `datT2` in `ui.R` as output of `data <- reactive({ ...`.

I tried in **server**:

```
  output$datainput <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
    datein<-data ()
    })
```

and **ui.R**

```
datT2<-DT::dataTableOutput("datainput ")
```

BUT it does not work.
Goal: To use the structure of the data within `ui.R` which user selected in `ui.R`.
Any idea how can I pass the read data in server to `ui.R`?

I tried even in `ui.R`

```
datT2<-uiOutput("datainput ")
```

and got the following error:

```
Warning: Error in :=: Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
  48: stop
  47: :=
```

I want just to read the data in `ui.R` dynamically. Something like:

```
     selectInput(inputId = 'date',
              label = 'Stichtag:',
              choices = list.files('./data', full.names = FALSE,
                       recursive = FALSE)),
...
datT2<-fread(paste0('./data/',input$date),header=TRUE, sep=";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE , encoding="UTF-8")
```

I need something like sing JavaScript objects within `ui.R`

Comment: I did not entirely understand what you want to achive, but the only non-hacky way of getting data from `server.R` to `ui.R` is to use the `*Output()` and `render*()` function pairs. So in your case either `renderUI()` and `uiOutput()` or `renderHTML()` and `htmlOutput()` may provide what you need.

Comment: Take a look at [uiOutput and renderUI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/renderUI.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Shiny - ui.R seems to not recognize a dataframe read by server.R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833631/r-shiny-ui-r-seems-to-not-recognize-a-dataframe-read-by-server-r)